# MS Access Windows Media Player Plugin in Fullscreen

Tags: vba, ms-access, windows-media-player

I have a windows media player plugin in my database to play training videos. I added a button to make the video play in full screen, which worked perfectly until recently.

Here is my code:

```
dim wmp as object
set wmp = me.wmp.object

wmp.fullscreen = true
```

Now when I click the fullscreen button, the video flashes to full screen for a split second, then goes back to just the normal play window in the database.

I can right click the video and make it play in full screen, but that is a tall ask for my users.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What changed recently - Windows or Access update, new hardware?

Comment: What plugin? I tried code with ActiveX WMP and it fails on FullScreen.

Comment: @June7 This is an enterprise computer so we get the monthly windows updates. I don't think Access has been updated in a while. 

I'm using the ActiveX WMP plugin as well.

Comment: Must be something else about this setup I am not aware of because I can't get your code to work at all. Might post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Well my codes not working for me either lol. 

My original code was just this: 'Me.WMP.fullscreen = true'
I tried that other code yesterday to see if it would work, but they both result in a flash of fullscreen before going back to the window view.

Comment: Oh, one thing worth noting is that you actually have to have a video playing for the code to work, otherwise it throws an error.

Comment: Okay, finally got it to work. Had to put your code in its own button. Initiate play with WMP button then click command button. Goes to full screen and stays until play ends. Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: It's probably something to do with setup. Thanks for checking!